# Valid work around for passing multiple args to multi processor pool?

Tags: python

Looks like you can only pass a single interatable item in the parts to a pool. I am wondering if it's a valid idea to set some lists as global and call on them from the pool function as I need to perform some operations on the initial list. Is there any convention on how big a var I can set as global? What would be good practice for setting stuff to global?